# Kiel funkcias -iĝ kun verbaj radikoj?

Tags: verbs

Mi vidis ekzemplojn kiel "sidiĝi" kaj "decidiĝi". Sed en mia kapo tio ŝajnas nelogike. Ĉu vere eblas iĝi verbo? Laŭ PIV sidiĝi signifas "iĝi sidanta" kaj same decidiĝi signifas "iĝi decidanta".

Estas ankaŭ tiuj verboj kiuj funkcias malsame. Vekiĝi, ekzemple. Oni ne iĝas vekanta.

Ĉu iu povus klarigi al mi?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tiu faceto de `sidiĝi` - iĝi sidanta - signifas *ŝanĝon al iu stato*.

```
sidiĝi
eksidi
sidigi sin
```

Same kia `blankiĝi` signifas ŝanĝon de neblanka al blanka.

Ĉe `vekiĝi` alia faceto ekzistas: la funkcio estas turni transitivan verbon en netransitivan verbon. Kompare kun aktiva voĉo al pasiva voĉo.

```
la vekhorloĝo vekis min
mi estis vekita
mi vekiĝis
```

La sufikso **-ig** inverse turnas netransitivan verbon en transitivan.

```
mi kuŝas
la kuracisto kuŝigas min
```

Comment: Ĉu *vekhorloĝo*?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev korektite.